# What is this mysterious 'touch-and-hold' sweet spot that keeps minimizing my app, and can I disable it?

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

I've developed a game engine for Android in Java, and it's designed to create two-dimensional platforming games. The main character moves left or right in response to the user touching and holding a finger within one of two invisible 'bands' running vertically along the left and right boundaries of the screen. The game is designed to work in both portrait and landscape views, and the location of the invisible bands updates accordingly.

During initialize, I do the following with my SurfaceView object:

```
// Set the content to appear full screen, and to allow the navigation bars
// to be pulled up from offscreen with a swipe action at the screen's edge.
a_GameView.setSystemUiVisibility(
   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION        // hide nav bar
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN             // hide status bar
 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
   );
```

In portrait mode, it plays like a dream. The problem arises when you play in landscape view. Let's say I've rotated my phone 90 degrees clockwise--now, what used to be the top of my screen is where my right band is, and what used to be the bottom of my screen is where my left band is. Having the character move left works ~99% of the time, but if you press your finger against one sweet spot (exactly where the home button would be, if my app weren't hiding it), you get an undesirable reaction. The phone vibrates once very lightly, the app continues running, but as soon as you let go, you get a second light vibration and the app minimizes, putting you back at the home screen.

It doesn't seem like this is the same as tapping the home button, because this only happens when you press and hold. It can't be caused by tapping the sweet spot rapidly.

**My question is**: can anybody explain to me what mechanism of the Android OS controls this reaction, and is it possible for me to disable *just that* mechanism?

Obviously I want the user to be able to exit the app at any time, but I want to enforce that they must perform an upward swipe to 'pull up' the nav bar to get out. I don't want this one touchable sweet spot to exist, because I don't want the user accidentally minimizing the game while trying to move their character.

Any insight much appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Since posting this I have confirmed this does not happen on an LG G5. This only happens on the Samsung Galaxy S8+ I've been using for development, so it seems to be unique to specific flavor(s) of Android.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I've finally found an answer. The mysterious sweet spot is the result of the 'Hard press Home button' feature in the Samsung Galaxy S8+. It can be disabled at: Settings -> Display -> Navigation Bar.

The feature allows you to press the home button even when it isn't visible by applying more pressure than normal. It's the extra pressure that triggers it, not actually a 'touch-and-hold' action as I'd initially described.